# Why can Laravel not see my variable (Undefined variable error)?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to pass through my `$categories` variable to my shop view and I am getting an `Undefined variable` error from Laravel. I'm passing it in through a controller along with a `$products` variable. Here is the controller:

```php
public function US()
{
    $US_products = Product::all()->where('US', '=', '1');
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('shop.shopUS')->with([
        'products', $US_products,
        'categories', $categories,
    ]);
}
```

And here is how I am calling it in my shopNew.blade.php:

```html
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <div class="categoryOption">
        <a href="#">{{ $category->name }}</a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

When I `dd($category)` in my controller, the category is successfully gathered and the `$product` variable works perfectly when called the exact same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
return view('shop.shopUS')->with([
    'products', $US_products,
    'categories', $categories,
]);
```

to

```
return view('shop.shopUS',[
    'products'=> $US_products,
    'categories'=> $categories,
]);
```

or

```
return view('shop.shopUS')->with(
    'products', $US_products
    
)->with(
    'categories', $categories,        
);
```

or another way

```
return view('shop.shopUS')->with([
    'products'=> $US_products,
    'categories'=> $categories,
]);
```

see [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#creating-and-rendering-views)

Answer (score 0):

Using compact() you can change your code to this (**clean and shorter code**):

```
   public function US(){
    $products = Product::all()->where('US', '=', '1');
    $categories = Category::all();
     return view('shop.shopUS',compact('products','categories'));
  }
```